# Find a vector that will make the set linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education, independence, learning

I have a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$:
$\Biggl{\{}$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$,$\mathbf{\vec{v}}$$\Biggl{\}}$

I want to be able to find the values for $\mathbf{\vec{v}}$ so that the set is linearly independent, but I am not sure what I need to do to find that.
I know that the first two vectors are independent so I just need to find a single vector that is not in any relation to the first two so that it could make the set dependent.

What I have tried is turning the set into an augmented matrix to get:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & a & 0 \\
    2& 2& b& 0\\
    3& 3& c& 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Which becomes:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 0& \frac{(b+a)}{3} & 0 \\
    0& 1& \frac{3(b-2a)}{18}& 0\\
    0& 0& 2(c-3a)-3(B-2A)& 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

But I do not know where to go after this, is there an easier way to solve this sort of question that I am missing?

How could I find $\mathbf{\vec{v}}$ so that this set is independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is very good; the last column can be omitted, as it stays zero. I use a different elimination method, top down.
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
2 & 2 & b \\
3 & -3 & c
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
0 & -2 & b-2a \\
0 & -9 & c-3a
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
0 & 1 & (2a-b)/2 \\
0 & -9 & c-3a
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
0 & 1 & (2a-b)/2 \\
0 & 0 & c-3a+\frac{9}{2}(2a-b)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The condition that the vectors are linearly independent is that
$$
c-3a+\frac{9}{2}(2a-b)\ne0
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
12a-9b+2c\ne0
$$
Just find three numbers with this property and you're done.